# Rails Methods that call themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, enums, model, state

In Rails is there a way that I can make a method call itself based on a change in the database? For instance, lets say I have two classes: `Products` and `Orders`.

Orders have three possible enum values:

```
    class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      enum status: [:pending, :processing,:shipped]
      belongs_to :products
     end
```

I would like to batch process `Orders` so when a product has 50 orders, I want it to set all Orders associated with it to processed. `Orders` default to `:pending`. To change an order to `:processing` I would call `order.processing!`. I could write a method into the Products model like:

```
def process_orders
  if self.orders.count=50
  self.orders.each do |order|
  order.processing!
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that I would have to call the `process_orders` method for it to execute, is there anyway I could make it automatically execute once a product has 50 orders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sounds like a good opportunity to use an [Active Record Callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  after_save do
    product.process_orders if product.pending_threshold_met?
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def pending_threshold_met?
    orders.where(status: :pending).count >= 50
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) to update the `status` column of all of your orders at once rather looping through them one by one:

```
self.orders.update_all(status: :processing)
```

and wrap that inside a callback.

Something like this:

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save do
      product.process_orders if product.has_fifty_pending_orders?
    end

    # rest of your model code
  end

  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    # rest of your model code

    def process_orders
      self.orders.update_all(status: :processing)
    end

    def has_fifty_pending_orders?
      self.orders.where(status: :pending).count >= 50
    end
  end
```